# unknown record property/related component "onwer" on "contact"

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

When I try to execute php `symfony doctrine:data-load`, this message apears :

> unknown record property/related component "owner" on "contact"

this is my schema.yml :

```
Contact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: contact
  columns:
    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)

      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fonction_organisme:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    categorie:
      type: string(300)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    region:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    province:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    adresse:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel1:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel2:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel3:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    tel4:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fax:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    ville:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    journal:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    commentaire:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fix:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    image:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Evenement:
      local: id_contact
      foreign: id_contact_event
      type: many
    users : 
      class : user
      refclass : operation_contact
      foreignAlias : contacts
Courrier:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: courrier
  columns:
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    annee:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_c:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    exp:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    dest:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    state:
      type: string(10)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    objet:
      type: string(1000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    image_c:
      type: string(500)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_recep:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    date_env:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    owner_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_c:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations :
     users : 
      class : user
      refclass : operation_c
      foreignAlias : courriers
Evenement:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: evenement
  columns:
    id_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    date:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    action:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_contact_event:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Contact:
      local: id_contact_event
      foreign: id_contact
      type: one
OperationC:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: operation_c
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    num_serie:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation_c:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op_c:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations : 
      user : { onDelete : CASCADE}
      courrier : { onDelete : CASCADE }
OperationContact:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: operation_contact
  columns:
    id_contact:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    operation:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    date_op:
      type: date(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations : 
      user : { onDelete : CASCADE}
      contact : { onDelete : CASCADE }
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    id_user:
      type: integer(2)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    nom_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    prenom_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    adresse_user:
      type: string(2000)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    tel_user:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    login:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

and this is an example from my fixture file :

```
  contact :
    jihane:
       nom : jihane bahadi
       fonction_organisme : directrice
       categorie : autre
       region : meknes
       adresse : route de fes
       tel1 : 0654789632
       email : jihane.bahadi@gmail.com
       fix : 05698743255
       ville : meknes
       ouwner : user
```

Comment: Is it a typo `ouwner : user`? Should be `owner : user`.

Comment: well , it's just an example , i'll try to change this "user" i'll put another name and i'll see !

Comment: it's the same problem , i've put owner : sara and i've got the same problem

Comment: Did you rebuild your model, class, db, etc .. ?

Comment: i think that another problem appears , when i try to execute doctrine:insert-sql another time , i get an error about a foreign key the error = <ernno : 121 >

Comment: well , i solved the problem of this error ( errno : 121 ) , i re-created the table (in phpmyadmin) with it's foreign key and i rebuild the schema , model ... , but i still have the problem of the data-load . i mad owner as a comment in my fixture file , but when i execute doctrine:data-load , i get unknown record property/related component "categorie" on "contact" , i think it means that the problem is not in the fixture file , can it be a problem in my relations in schema.yml ????

Comment: I think you should work on the case of your model names and relations in your schema and fixtures. There's so much inconsistency it's hard to know what's a relation and what's a model attribute. For example, have you tried simply capitalizing the `c` in `contact` in your fixture? Your model is `Contact`, not `contact`. Class names in PHP are case-sensitive.

Comment: i've tried to use "Contact" in my fixture , and just about the relations in my schema , all names are capitalized , but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm not sure but i think this is because you use owner for a field name!(it confuses the mySQL with the owner Reserved wrod!) i remember once i was using the word **group** for one of my fields or models and it caused so many problems. but when i changed that name everything went fine. just change the **owner** in your model schema and then build your models,forms,etc and recreate your tables and fix your fixture. i hope this fix the problem!